# genisoimage уникальность имен файлов

Tags: linux

При создании исошника genisoimage ругается на неуникальность имен двух файлов Чертеж_1.dwg и Чертеж_1.pdf. Причем, если раскидать эти файлы по разным папкам, ошибок не появляется.

```
os.system('genisoimage -v -J -r -V {} -o "{}{}.iso" "{}" | grep "extents written"'.format(datestr,out_dir,datestr,in_dir))
```

Есть варианты это вылечить?

Comment: а если их переименовать `s/чертеж/churtezh/`?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin мне каждет жульета или рокрижд ругается - я бы оставил только udf

Comment: переименование - не вариант, предполагается автоматическое формирование.

Comment: если ограничить длину имени восемью символами, то имена получаются одинаковые. вывод: не надо ограничивать длину. почитайте в man-е кто из них — `-J` или `-r` ограничивает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй UDF вместо Joliet и Rock Ridge. Это более современная ФС для ISO дисков.

Joliet вводит дополнительный набор имён для файлов. Имена имеют длину до 64 символов Unicode и хранятся в кодировке UCS-2.

Rock Ridge хранит атрибуты POSIX и имена файлов до 255.

Кстати у меня не воспроизводится проблема. cdrtools версии 3.02a09

Похоже проблема в генерации файла TRANS.TBL для Вашего набора файлов.

Comment: astralinux Смоленск :)

Comment: попробуй всеже убрать -r и -J. так как это исошки думаю функционал дозаписи врятли нужен.

Comment: -J убрал - помогло. Но сколько теперь будет максимальная длина имени файла?

Comment: -UDF добавь и будет максимально возможная

Comment: c -udf все хорошо получилось. И с кодировкой проблема ушла.

Comment: @Boliwar можно поставить галочку на ответе.